# How does the root in spanning tree protocol works?

Tags: network, arp-spoofing

I am studying spanning tree protocol attacks and I would like to understand a thing. The root is on the "top" of the tree, how can we exploit this to put in place an attack? We can, in some way, become the root, but what privileges would we get doing this? I don't get if the root can read all the packets, because I thought that if two host are connected in a "sub-part" of the tree, the root doesn't see any message, or am I wrong?

So it would be useful just because I have more chances to read more messages but I will never see ALL the messages, right?

Another thing, how can I put in place an arp spoofing attack being the root?

Comment: Everything you said so far seems to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

The exploit here would effectively be a Denial of Service attack.

When a new Root bridge is elected in the STP topology, the entire Layer 2 network needs to re-converge, during this time every switch has to move through the STP states (Listening, Learning) to discover the new STP topology, during the initial states MAC addresses are not stored in MAC tables and no frames are forwarded meaning that during this time (30 seconds for 802.1D) no traffic is being moved through the network.

The affect of this can be prolonged by constantly forcing the network to re-converge between the “real” Root bridge and the attackers fake Root bridge.

Answer (score 0):

> The root is on the "top" of the tree, how can we exploit this to put in place an attack?

The basic idea is to draw traffic to the attacker's switch. That isn't easy however, placement of the switch is crucial. You'll need to attach the switch to multiple switches, as close to the original root bridge as possible - keep in mind that traffic always uses the shortest path through the tree's branches (avoiding blocked links), not necessarily through the root.

> We can, in some way, become the root, but what privileges would we get doing this?

STP doesn't use a privilege system. Any bridge can become root *unless you take active measures against that*. Configuring all switch ports towards any else than the normal and the backup root with the `root-guard` option is highly advisable.

> I don't get if the root can read all the packets, because I thought that if two host are connected in a "sub-part" of the tree, the root doesn't see any message, or am I wrong?

That's correct. The root doesn't force all traffic through its ports. However, it roots the spanning tree and practically represents the network center. Traffic between non-adjacent switches is *likely* to flow through the root, but that depends on the overall topology.

> So it would be useful just because I have more chances to read more messages but I will never see ALL the messages, right?

Exactly.

> Another thing, how can I put in place an arp spoofing attack being the root?

ARP spoofing always works the same way, regardless whether you are (attached to) the root bridge or not. ARP spoofing tries to associate the attacker's MAC address with the attacked IP address - this is a network layer attack. STP works on the data link layer.